# Change Xcode Managed Signing Certificate for Team

Tags: xcode, code-signing-certificate

I'm using `xcode 9` and have a working distribution profile for releasing apps to the App Store. I'm using my team profile but the signing certificate is set to my iPhone developer cert and has my personal name on it. I would like to create a certificate that has the company name and use that to sign production release apps.  How can I go about this?

Update -- 
When I look at the project structure in XCode, specifically the signing section, there are options to select which Team the app will be published with and directly under that is the signing certificate to be used.  There is one cert displayed and its not changeable.  That cert clearly shows as my "iPhone developer" certificate with my full name.  I would like this to be a team certificate.  I'm using XCode managed signing and the info icon next to the profile displays "Certificates: 1 Included. Includes newest signing certificate iPhone Developer: My Name (#####)".

When I look into the Keychain Access app I can see my developer cert, personal cert and team cert for iPhone Distribution (the one I would like to use).  I'm not sure how to get this into the provisioning profile so it can be selected when signing an app.

Comment: Certificates do not have "names" attached to them, so it's unclear what you think is wrong or what change you would like to make.

Comment: I've updated the question with more details to better explain what I'm asking